# different sequelize behavior between findOne vs. findAll on a joined table

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm trying to change a findAll function to a findOne function since I decided that I only need a single record.

But the code that worked for findAll results in a error when changed to findOne.

I looked at the SQL query that sequelize made, and the JOIN query location seems to be a bit off, making the query not discover the joined table.

I've tried including/excluding raw: true, but with the same results.

Below is the findAll code that works:

```
const member = await ManageMember.findAll({
  attributes: [
    ['id', 'memberIdx'],
    [Sequelize.col('manage_brand.id'), 'brandIdx'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: ManageBrand,
      attributes: [],
      as: 'manage_brand',
    },
  ],
  where: {
    email: 'test@aaa.aaa',
  },
  raw: true,
});
```

the resulting SQL query:

```
SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`,
       `manage_brand`.`id`  AS `brandIdx`
FROM   `manage_member` AS `manage_member`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand`
                    ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberidx`
                       AND ( `manage_brand`.`deletedat` IS NULL )
WHERE  ( `manage_member`.`deletedat` IS NULL
         AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa' );
```

the result of the query:

```
[ { memberIdx: 29, brandIdx: 11 } ]
```

the resulting SQL query when changing findAll to findOne:

```
SELECT `manage_member`.*
FROM   (SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`,
               `manage_brand`.`id`  AS `brandIdx`,
               `manage_member`.`id`
        FROM   `manage_member` AS `manage_member`
        WHERE  ( `manage_member`.`deletedat` IS NULL
                 AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa' )
        LIMIT  1) AS `manage_member`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand`
                    ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberidx`
                       AND ( `manage_brand`.`deletedat` IS NULL );
```

the error when executing the query

```
Error
    at Query.run (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:52:25)
    at /home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:314:28
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)
    at async manage_member.findAll (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1134:21)
    at async manage_member.findOne (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1228:12)
    at async Object.wtf (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/src/auth/auth.repository.js:319:20)
    at async /home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/test.js:9:16 {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Unknown column 'manage_brand.id' in 'field list'
      at Packet.asError (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Query.execute (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'manage_brand.id' in 'field list'",
    sql: "SELECT `manage_member`.* FROM (SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`, `manage_brand`.`id` AS `brandIdx`, `manage_member`.`id` FROM `manage_member` AS `manage_member` WHERE (`manage_member`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa') LIMIT 1) AS `manage_member` LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand` ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberIdx` AND (`manage_brand`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);",
    parameters: undefined
  },
  original: Error: Unknown column 'manage_brand.id' in 'field list'
      at Packet.asError (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Query.execute (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/cnc4ever/pops_brand_back/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'manage_brand.id' in 'field list'",
    sql: "SELECT `manage_member`.* FROM (SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`, `manage_brand`.`id` AS `brandIdx`, `manage_member`.`id` FROM `manage_member` AS `manage_member` WHERE (`manage_member`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa') LIMIT 1) AS `manage_member` LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand` ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberIdx` AND (`manage_brand`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);",
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: "SELECT `manage_member`.* FROM (SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`, `manage_brand`.`id` AS `brandIdx`, `manage_member`.`id` FROM `manage_member` AS `manage_member` WHERE (`manage_member`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa') LIMIT 1) AS `manage_member` LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand` ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberIdx` AND (`manage_brand`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);",
  parameters: {}
}
```

The closest I've managed to make it work is, when I add the attribute in the include section, and comment out the Sequelize.col part in the attribute section. It works, but I need to alias it, but aliasing it will result in the same above error.

this works:

```
const member = await ManageMember.findOne({
  attributes: [
    ['id', 'memberIdx'],
    // [Sequelize.col('manage_brand.id'), 'brandIdx'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: ManageBrand,
      attributes: ['id'],
      as: 'manage_brand',
    },
  ],
  where: {
    email: 'test@aaa.aaa',
  },
  raw: true,
});
```

the query:

```
SELECT `manage_member`.*,
       `manage_brand`.`id` AS `manage_brand.id`
FROM   (SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`,
               `manage_member`.`id`
        FROM   `manage_member` AS `manage_member`
        WHERE  ( `manage_member`.`deletedat` IS NULL
                 AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa' )
        LIMIT  1) AS `manage_member`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand`
                    ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberidx`
                       AND ( `manage_brand`.`deletedat` IS NULL );
```

resulting in:

```
{ memberIdx: 29, id: 29, 'manage_brand.id': 11 }
```

Is this working as intended? Or am I doing something wrong?

For the record, I'm using sequelize 6.25.5, thank you so much!

Comment: Try adding `subQuery: false` at top level.  in `findOne` code, Sequelize is trying to "optimize" it to subquery but sometimes Sequelize cannot construct it correctly.

Comment: @Emma Your solution worked perfectly thank you so much! now that I know what to search for, there are a LOT of subQuery discussions! Just wish sequelize would work reliably :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @emma, I was able to solve the issue.

By adding subQuery: false to the top level, the query resulted in:

```
SELECT `manage_member`.`id` AS `memberIdx`,
       `manage_brand`.`id`  AS `brandIdx`
FROM   `manage_member` AS `manage_member`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `manage_brand` AS `manage_brand`
                    ON `manage_member`.`id` = `manage_brand`.`memberidx`
                       AND ( `manage_brand`.`deletedat` IS NULL )
WHERE  ( `manage_member`.`deletedat` IS NULL
         AND `manage_member`.`email` = 'test@aaa.aaa' )
LIMIT  1
```

just adding LIMIT 1 to the end of the findAll query. Still think it's a weird behavior, but the folks at sequelize seem to be aware of this.

Thank you again @emma!!